# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $f(x)= x^2 , x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = ax+b, x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f(x)= x^2 , x \in \mathbb{Q}$

$f(x)= ax+b, x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$

If $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$, then values of $a$ and $b$ are?

How do i start this?
Thanks

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$ then it has to be continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @Winther and f is continous at values of x where $x^2-ax-b=0$. What next?

Comment: Start by taking the limit $x\to 1$ along irrational values. This limit must agree with the function value $f(1)=1$. This gives you an equation relating $a$ and $b$. Then do a similar thing for the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ has to be continous at $x=1$. Thus we have
$$a+b=f(1)=\lim_{x\to 1}x^2=1$$
To be differentiable we need
$$2=(x^2)'(1)=(ax+b)'(1)=a$$
So we get $a=2$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little

Comment: You must get sure that it works  for $\mathbb{Q}$ and for $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ like written in the comment. So you get the conditions. Can you say in more detail, what's unclear?

Comment: The differentiability part

Comment: The difference quotient must converg in both situations so you get the condition.